# Vines for XMPP Server rather than other solutions

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to xmpp and all that implies.  I'm a RoR Developer and I need to use a xmpp server for a project.  On top of that, I will need to do some heavy customization so that my rails app can create users, make them friends, track all communication, etc.

Being a ruby developer, and someone who likes nice (looking) things, I REALLY want to use vines for the xmpp server.  It's in ruby, it's friendly, I like it: http://www.getvines.org/

But, other things like ejabberd, Tigase, etc have much more reputation, and I guess they have a better community.  I'm guessing this because finding tutorials seems far too difficult.

So I'm looking for someone to tell me why Vines is not a good solution for XMPP, and what I should use instead.  Because otherwise, I'm opting to use Vines =)

Thanks!

Comment: This should obviously be closed as it is soliciting opinions.  But I will say that all your customizations are pretty much doable via XMPP on any server.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this later, I've learned a good bit today about vines.

Firstly, it seems the entire thing was made by one developer, who has since started fulltime jobs for twitter then github.  So there is not likely to be new features or updates coming to vines.

Second, is there is virtually no community build around vines.  It's very hard to troubleshoot issues.

Hope this info helps others!